# Is it okay to fire a query for each input field change in a big web form?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am developing a mark/score entry portal for an institution using php and html, which looks similiar to an excel sheet, where the faculties would enter scores for about 20 questions against a student's name. In each of those pages, there would be about 60 students.

Is it okay to fire an update query for each change that would be done. Which would mean atleast 1200 update queries would be fired.

Reason for my confusion : I want the page to function exactly like an excel sheet, so that even if they refresh the page without submitting the form, details remain as such.

Is there any risk such as DB overload involved in this ?

Comment: If i understood you correctly, you would make the update requests one by one, as the user edit each field? That should be fine, since they all wouldn't be triggered at the same time.

Comment: Yes. You are right. thats what I am planning. Thanks for your response !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be alright, if a user will be making entry one-by-one. However, if there is a scenario in which a user will be able to make a bulk update, i.e. more than one field at a time, you might want to come up with an optimized solution by implementing [Unit of Work](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b1df45/unit-of-work-in-repository-pattern/) design pattern. The idea behind it is to accumulate and combine all pending queries to the DB and send them all at once with one query, thus greatly optimizing performance.
Also, it would be best to make use of [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp) in your project to make the user experience more smooth. You don't want to interrupt a user every time they update a field with a page reload.

Comment: As you rightly mentioned, I  am currently using AJAX for this purpose as the change is done one field at a time. But, I will also familiarize myself with the design pattern you had mentioned :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be okay, databases are built to handle millions of record's CRUD Operations, 1200 seems too little and also according to your requirements all the write operations are not executed at the same time, so things should be fine ;)

If you want to have a more reliable solution you can always have 2 database servers where one only does the writes and another does the reads and also there are so much solutions to optimize the database based on what type of database u r using, you can always do a google search and find them, let me know the database that u r using, if you need any help on them!

Comment: I shall google about this and get back to you. Thank you

Comment: Your welcome and if this answer meets your expectations, please do accept the answer, Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

It would be fine if you are using an AJAX to perform the update operations. Because for every change the AJAX is called and an update operation is done. PHP can handle millions of operations so you dont need to worry about DB overload or something